# Jquery toggle display before animation?

Tags: jquery, css, html

Im looking to toggle a display:none on and off using jquery before another jquery animation. I need the content to be hidden and withdrawn from the document flow. This will fix another issue I have been having with overlapping divs ontop of eachother. I have looked into using the absolute postioning for this, but absolute would remove the content from the low of the document causeing the entire layout to collapse and break.

The only solution I have come across that I think would work is removing all the divs from the page and inserting them as needed. This would allow me to keep parent child link between the content divs and the container divs.

I have a simplified JsFiddle that shows the basics of the current Jquery Animations. I need all the panels to stack, and allow the container div (Parent) to pull the Content div (Child) height.

(Container div is not in example.)

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BeU3U/44/

```
    var settings = {
    objSlideTrigger: '.trigger', // link button id
    objSlidePanel: '' // slide div class or id
}

$(settings.objSlideTrigger).bind('click' , function() {

    if ( $('.panel').hasClass('out') )
        slidePanelIn();

    /**
     *  I use the $(this).data('content')
     *  that's defined within the HTML attribute
     *  to know which DIV Content to collect, e.g.
     *
     *  If I click: 
     *      <a class="trigger" data-content="panel-one">
     *  I'll be opening up:
     *      <div id="panel-one" class="panel">Panel One</div>
    **/
    settings.objSlidePanel = "#"+ $(this).data('content') +"";        

    //If the panel isn't out
    if(!$(settings.objSlidePanel).hasClass('out')) {
        slidePanelOut();
    } else if($(settings.objSlidePanel).hasClass('out')) {
        slidePanelIn();
    } 
});

function slidePanelOut() {
    //Animate it to left 
    $(settings.objSlidePanel).animate({
        'right' : '-67%'
    });
    //Add the out class
    $(settings.objSlidePanel).addClass('out');
}
function slidePanelIn() {
    //Otherwise, animate it back in
    $(settings.objSlidePanel).animate({
        'right' : '-89%'
    });
    //Remove the out class
    $(settings.objSlidePanel).removeClass('out');
}
```

Container its children & Footer css. The content panels that slide in are held within the right panel.

```
#container {
height: ;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
height: auto;
z-index: 10;
}
#panel-left {
float: left;
width: 15%;
}
#panel-right {
float: right;
width: 85%;
}
#foot{
height: 100px;
background-color: yellow;
border-top: solid thin black;
width:100%;
z-index: 50;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you use position:relative in the parent div of the absolute positioned element it wont break your page, you got the javascript correct i think a css fix is your best bet. If your heights arent fixed then the div should expand to the content

Comment: This is what I dont understand, Ive spent the best part of the day trying just that but the container div just doesnt respond the way you are saying. When I position the container div (parent) relative, and the content div's (Child) absolute the children are completly removed from the flow of the document causing the container to close up and the footer to follow the container. :/ its really fustrating me.

Comment: add overflow:hidden the container shouldnt collapse

Comment: I have done, I needed to to stop the page from showing the divs hidden off to the right.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BeU3U/47/

```
<div class="container">
<div id="panel-one" class="panel">Panel One</div>
<div id="panel-two" class="panel">Panel Two</div>
<div id="panel-three" class="panel">Panel Three</div>
<div id="panel-four" class="panel"> Panel Four</div>
<div id="panel-five" class="panel">Panel Five</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container { position: relative; }
.panel {
        width:85%;
        padding:2%;
        right:-89%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index:2;
        color: white;
        background: #2F2F2F ;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        border-radius: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

   .trigger {
        width:10%;
        text-align:center;
        color:goldenrod;
        top:26px;
        padding:0.5% 0%;
        background:#2F2F2F ;
        right:30%;
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 5px;
    }enter code here
```

Comment: This does work for overlaping the divs but as i said before it collapses the container and the footer follows. Ill update the question adding in the container css and the footer css.

Comment: ya post your html/css and i might be able to help you further

Comment: if there is nothing in your container and no set height the container wont expand to the height of the sliding divs. This kind of looks like a mobile/tablet style site with the way you want to do panels. You should add a few rules CSS body, html{height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;} then set the height of your container to 100% and add a padding-bottom of 100px (this is needed to keep your footer stuck to the bottom) then add position: fixed, bottom: 0; to your footer. Let me know how that goes maybe ill try to put a fiddle together if i have time

Comment: Ill give it a go. Am I Including absolution positioning on the divs? aswell?

Comment: no the only divs that should have absolute are your panels, the footer should be fixed and your container relative

Comment: Ok progress, but the content panel (Child) is fairly large and the footer is obstructing the bottom of the content because the page will not scroll to the full length of the content div.

Comment: if the height of the container is 100%  set overflow to scroll, you might have to change the z-index of your panels to make sure they are above the footer, see if you can make a fiddle

Comment: Ill put one together now.

Comment: Heres that Js Fiddle of the site as it stands from the latest changes. http://jsfiddle.net/BeU3U/49/